# Difference between docker rm IMAGE vs docker rmi IMAGE

Tags: docker, microservices, docker-image

According to Docker documentations, `docker image rm` "Remove one or more images" [[1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/)]. `docker rmi` has a same description [[2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/)], but then it goes on to say "Removes (and un-tags) one or more images from the host node."

Do `docker image rm IMAGE` and `docker rmi IMAGE` have an identical effect under any scenario? `IMAGE` is ID of the particular image that is to be removed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[The man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/docker-rmi.1.html) for `docker rmi` specifies that `docker rmi` is an alias for `docker image rm`. I suppose the documentation from docker is a little bit inconsistent in that regard. They write all the details for `docker rmi` while the documentation for `docker image rm` is lackluster.

Comment: The `docker container ...` and `docker image ...` commands are newer, but there's a lot of older tutorials/scripts/experience that's used to using the older unqualified `docker run`  and `docker rmi` type commands.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `docker rm` is for containers and `docker rmi` is for images.

```
PS C:\Users\3des> docker rm httpd --force
Error: No such container: httpd
PS C:\Users\3des> docker rm httpd
Error: No such container: httpd
______________________________________________
PS C:\Users\3des> docker rmi httpd --force
Untagged: httpd:latest
Untagged: httpd@sha256:2fab99fb3b1c7ddfa99d7dc55de8dad0a62dbe3e7c605d78ecbdf2c6c49fd636
``
```

Comment: The question referenced `docker image rm`, not `docker rm`.

Answer (score -1):

1). The docker image rm command "Remove one or more containers" not container image.
to check for container and its ID "docker ps -a" command

2). However, the docker rmi command means rm = remove i = image.
it is used to removing docker images. remembers that containers are created from images.
the "docker images or docker image ls" shows images, repository, TAG, and image ID.
docker rmi <image_ID> to remove image.
NOTE even when it is possible to create a new image from the existing image using the "docker commit" command, such image will come it its unique image id.

Comment: This is false. you are confusing `docker image rm` with `docker rm`. The description of `docker image rm` [from the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/) confirms that it's `Remove one or more images`.